# Difficulty with wildcards when running a Perl script?

Tags: perl

I'm running a Perl script ([MOSS, Measure of Software Similarity](https://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/)) that uploads either a file or a folder of files to a server, but I'm running into some weird behaviors.

This is supposed to work:

```
mossnet.pl -l java -d Files/*/*.java
```

However, when I try that, I'm told Files/*/*.java does not exist (but it does).

But when I instead direct it to a specific file in that directory:

```
mossnet.pl -l java -d Files/foo/bar.java Files/foo2/bar2.java
```

It works correctly. So, it's able to see the directory structure, but it seems to trip when it's given wildcards.

Any suggestions?

If relevant: I'm on a PC, Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the args? e.g. `mossnet.pl -l java -d "Files/*/*.java"`

Comment: Yep, no luck there. I tried that, I've tried reversing the slashes, I've tried using the absolute path. Nothing seems to work so long as I'm using wildcards.

I tried on my Mac as well, but there it's not even working when providing a direct path to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's relevant that you're on Windows. Wildcard expansion in the Windows shell is buggy and the docs recommend (and provide a technique) to handle them yourself:

http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.23.2/README.win32#Command-line_Wildcard_Expansion

> The default command shells on DOS descendant operating systems (such as they are) usually do not expand wildcard arguments supplied to programs. They consider it the application's job to handle that. This is commonly achieved by linking the application (in our case, perl) with startup code that the C runtime libraries usually provide. However, doing that results in incompatible perl versions (since the behavior of the argv expansion code differs depending on the compiler, and it is even buggy on some compilers). Besides, it may be a source of frustration if you use such a perl binary with an alternate shell that *does* expand wildcards.
>
> Instead, the following solution works rather well. The nice things about it are 1) you can start using it right away; 2) it is more powerful, because it will do the right thing with a pattern like */*/*.c; 3) you can decide whether you do/don't want to use it; and 4) you can extend the method to add any customizations (or even entirely different kinds of wildcard expansion).

```
    # Wild.pm - emulate shell @ARGV expansion on shells that don't
    use File::DosGlob;
    @ARGV = map {
                  my @g = File::DosGlob::glob($_) if /[*?]/;
                  @g ? @g : $_;
                } @ARGV;
    1;
```

To use this, you would do something like

```
    C:\> set PERL5OPT=-MWild
    C:\> mossnet.pl -l java -d Files/*/*.java
```

or

```
    C:\> perl -MWild mossnet.pl -l java -d Files/*/*.java
```

(or you could put the above code at the beginning of your script)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this at some point, but it definitely sounds like it would work -- for now I'm sticking to running it on a Mac, which is working for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple wild cards in the path, like

```
Files/*/*.java
```

may not be supported in some basic versions of Windows shell cmd.exe

You may want to try using Power shell or some other shell like Cygwin for this functionality

Try

```
dir Files/*/*.java
```

or some other command like ls or type in the shell to see if it supports this.

Comment: Alright, working in PowerShell now -- dir Files/*/*.java works, but the command above still returns the same result: that the file does not exist.

Comment: Worth noting: it doesn't even work with one such wildcard. Even if I specify two folders that I know exist and use only the wildcard in *.java, it still reports that the "file" does not exist.

Comment: From your description "uploads either a file or a folder", it seems it can handle one file or one folder at a time. Could you try with a folder that has some *.java files?

Comment: That's what I'm trying. Right now I'm trying the simplest case: a folder with a single Java file. When I pass the entire path (Files/Java/file.java), it works. When I replace file.java with *.java, it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean specifying a folder name as argument.       mossnet.pl -l java -d Files/foo2                  If you try this, does it upload all the files in folder 'f002' ?

Comment: Oh, good question.

No, it says that the file path is not a text file. I think when the documentation says you can upload 'folders', the wildcard syntax is what it's referring to -- that with wildcards you can upload everything in a folder.